# How to run ember-cli with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, ember.js, ember-cli

Does anyone tried to run ember, especially with ember-cli inside Symfony application? I am actually trying to use prerender.io to achieve this. Doing it simply without ember-cli works, but with it, things getting complicated. Main problem is in

```
ember server
```

how to overcome this, so assets are build (or just easily watched).

```
ember build --watch
```

is actually really slow, around 4sec to build on every change is a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting errors? What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Have you succeeded? I'm on the same line here. But I did used another approach, I'm starting the a server instead, in a bash file like this:

```
ember s --output-path=$SF_DIR/web/app
```

Then on a sf twig view, included the index.html. It works fast, but looses the livereload feature since it's not made to work outside root. Can you tell me how you did resolve your sf2+ember-cli architecture?

Hope it helps, thanks!

Comment: I've actually went with different approach. Made SF as API, and Ember as purely front-end based and deploying them separately. In the end I did not find any benefit in including it in Symfony app.